# What is the purpose of external terminals on a logic probe?

Tags: test-equipment

I have [an LP-3500 logic probe](http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/LP-3500%5E1.pdf). In addition to the normal connectors to power and ground at the bottom, it comes with two external terminals (one red, one black), which can be connected on the side near the tip:

[image]
What is the purpose of the external terminals, and how are they used?

Comment: Sometimes you just don't want to sit and work with your hands occupied with this thing, but have it clipped to your circuit to allow you to do some other stuff in the same time.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So would you use a terminal in place of either the ground or power connector at the bottom or in place of the tip?

Comment: Do you have a manual for it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do not have a manual for it.

Comment: I'd assume red is to hook up a more permanent probing to watch rather than using the needle. Black may be to attach a more local logic reference point, or differential signal,  rather than the power ground, but without the manual the latter is just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector is just connected directly to the main probe, but some of the attachments are easier for certain things than others. There is one which is an alligator clip, and the other one is a hook probe. If you press the bottom of the hook clip, you should see a small metal hook slide out of the top. You can put a lead or wire through it, then release the bottom, and the hook will retract, clamping the lead or wire under it.

Comment: Thanks. It confused me that they were red and black, which I associate with power and ground.

Comment: if this helped you, could you please accept this answer? The reputation helps my beginner account, and anyone who has this same question will be able to find the answer easier. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I was waiting until I could go to the lab to test your answer. I now know you were indeed correct. Thanks for solving the mystery.